# Did Gon know it was Ponzu who died?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Let me quote [Hunterpedia](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Ponzu#Chimera_Ant_arc) for a refresher of what happened:

> However, before they get the chance, Zazan's squad detects them and Ponzu is the only one able to escape. When Pokkle was knocked out, she immediately runs for it. Knowing that Pokkle won't be eaten immediately, she rushed to write SOS messages in blood and uses her bees to bring the message to the strongest Hunter nearby--who happens to be Kite. When she finally decided to go back to the border, she is shot and eaten moments later by an officer from Zazan's squad.

When Gon arrived at the scene much later, all that remained was a puddle of blood and cloth and he looked angry.

Did he realize the victim was Ponzu?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

During the hunter exam Gon followed Ponzu's scent and he was also aware of her bee breeding ability. so we can assume that he understood from the moment they received the letter.